# Условие с паузами на Питоне

Tags: python

Верно ли записаны строчки с "time.sleep", в качестве единого условия? —

```
def _sleep(self):
    """Sleep a short time if self.sleep is set. Called before each request to instagram.com."""
    if self.sleep:
        time.sleep(6)
        time.sleep(min(random.expovariate(1), 40))
```

Задача в том, чтобы в условие "if self.sleep:", входили две нижеследующие строки, а не первая из них.

Comment: неужели не получается запустить и проверить?

Comment: @Эникейщик, я в Питоне вообще не разбираюсь. Строку "time.sleep(6)" пытаюсь добавить в чужой мудрёный скрипт, и что-то мне подсказывает, что если отдельно проверить — в таком виде код работать не будет.

Comment: 1. Да, если отступы расставлены именно так, то условие будет влиять на обе последующие строчки. И вообще на любое количество последующих строчек для которых сохраняется такой отступ. 2. Если уж так получилось, что вам приходится править чужой код на питоне, то освойте хотя бы самые основы. Серьёзно, так будет проще, и убережёте себя от большого количество гемороя. 3. На этом сайте такие вопросы не любят, вы рисковали получить охапку минусов.